# Error 500 when trying to visit any developers.google.com page

Tags: subdomain, google-apps

This is not a programming question. It's really a question for Google Tech Support, but **they said they can't help me and directed me to post here**.

When I log in to my Google account, and try to visit any page within the subdomain *developers.google.com* (http or https), I get the following error:

> Internal server error
>
> An error occurred while trying to fulfill your request.
>
> Error: 500 Server Error

I am able to access any other subdomain of google.com, just not *developers*.

I tried the following scenarios:

I **can** access pages when:

1. I log out of my Google account
2. I use any other browser in which I'm not logged in to my Google account.
3. I log in to a different Google account

I **can't** access pages when:

1. I'm logged in to my Google account in any browser (tried with Chrome, Firefox, and Safari on Mac)
2. I've clear the browser's cookies and cache
3. Logged in to my Google account using Chrome or Safari for iOS

The only thing I'm trying to access developers.google.com for is to start programming with the Google Apps Admin SDK, for which I need access to developer pages. I am the super admin of my Google Apps domain, so I contacted Google Enterprise Tech Support and they just told me to "contact the developers." When I asked who that was, they directed me to this page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there might be a service disabled for the OU that your account is in. I would review the 'Other Google Services' section of the Admin console. If this is something you're doing in a production environment. I would move your account into a new test OU and enabled all services. From there you can disable services until you find the problem one.

I tried doing a bit of testing of this but I'm not sure what you have enabled/disabled and there's propagation to take into account too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I created a test super admin account to work from, then created a test OU, enabled all "Other Google Services" on that OU, moved my problem account to that OU, then waited a day, and it still has the same problem. Also, I forgot to mention above that I've been able to access the developers.google.com pages prior to last week, but nothing changed last week on our Google Apps domain. I went to those pages quite frequently while checking documentation for Google Apps Script, so I am 100% sure that it's been working under my account.

Comment: Update in case anyone comes across this in the future: It started working again on it's own, but I'm not sure if it was a problem with Google's servers that was fixed, or if it was something I did. Other than enabling/disabling services for a test OU, the only thing I changed was disabling the Translate API for my account in each of my Google Apps Script projects. It was enabled for two of my projects, and I'd never enabled it and didn't need it. That did not fix the issue, but about 2 days later the site started working again for me. Could have been related somehow.